# How to establish an RDP connection between Pi 3 and Windows?

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, c#

Per the question title, how do I establish an RDP connection from my Pi 3 running Windows IoT to another machine?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/RemoteDisplay.htm) in [Microsoft's IoT developer resources](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot) for this. The information in the tutorial looks reasonably thorough, but in summary:

- Make a note of your IoT Pi's IP address.
- From a PC on the same local network navigate to `http://{Pi's IP address}:8080`
- Choose the `Remote` option from the left hand menu
- Check the `Enable Window IoT Remote Server` box.
- On the PC, install the [Windows IoT Remote Client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/iot-remote-client/9nblggh5mnxz) app (apparently available only through that link, not searchable on the Windows store)
- Run the remote client app
- Punch in your Raspberry Pi's IP address and hit `Connect`